# Decision Report generation in Drools

Tags: drools

How can we generate a **decision report in Drools** like the **OPA Decision Report**.

I've tried to check the drools websites and all. But I couldn't find any concrete information regarding this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enable all your rules to report that they are fired.

You can do this by adding (e.g.) the output of a log file entry to the rules' right hand side (or even a simple println to some text file).

A more generic way can be achieved by adding an event listener. A "rule fired" event can then access the rule to retrieve a metadata item and write an entry to a log, or file, or store it in a list or whatever. Obviously this is cleaner and safer (you'll detect a missing metadata entry) and more flexible.

[My white paper](https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns) on rules design patterns describes a technique where you write rule to keep track of individual conditions being met by some fact, and at the end of rules firing or not, you can assess what isn't fulfilled. It requires more work than the "all-or-nothing" rule, but it isn't prohibitive (I think).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But in OPA, once the inferencing has been finished, we can see why the rule has been fired or why the rule hasn't been fired, which condition was not satisfied and all. Isn't that not possible in Drools without adding a event listener?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box feature. You can write your rules in a way that keep track of individual conditions being fulfilled. I've added a link to my white paper describing the technique.